# NoMethodError: undefined method `inet' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x007fc6fce38350>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Rails 5.1.2.

Генерирую файл schema.rb:

```
bundle exec rake db:schema:dump
```

Далее перехожу в `rails c` и меняю адаптер командой:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection :adapter => :nulldb
```

После выполняю `User.first` и получаю ошибку:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `inet' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x007fc6fce38350>
```

Ниже этой строки идут отсылки на эти строки в файле schema.rb:

```
t.inet "current_sign_in_ip"
t.inet "last_sign_in_ip"
```

В чем проблема и как ее решить?

Comment: Apparently your users table has an inet column in it so that part of your schema is PostgreSQL-specific.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849159/rake-is-aborting-because-undefined-method-inet-for-sqlite-db

Comment: поменяйте тип поля с inet на строку

Comment: @tcpack4 ага. И теперь вместо `inet` он пишет `json`. Такой себе фикс.

Comment: Очевидно, в адаптере `nulldb`, [в отличие от адаптера постгреса](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_definitions.rb#L89-L91), не реализована поддержка типа `inet`. Как решить? Доделать адаптер самостоятельно :D

Comment: @D-side ясно. А есть какие-нибудь альтернативы nulldb?

Comment: Может быть. Я не знаю, зачем он вам нужен изначально. Да и не думаю, что доделать адаптер космически сложно, раз уж на то пошло. Только зачем? Что вы выигрываете, задействуя такое решение?

Comment: @D-side при сборке проекта на сервере для теста логики схемы ДБ. Мол, код в моделях соответствует схеме.

Comment: Вопрос сохраняется: зачем? В схеме БД нет никакой логики, это результат работы миграций. Они либо отработали сразу правильно, а вы посмотрели дифф схемы, удовлетворились им и закоммитили результат; либо они отработали неправильно, содержимое диффа вас не устраивает, и вы сразу займётесь починкой. Какие ошибки вы собираетесь ловить такими тестами?